# Custom Dialog doesn't appears like is especified

Tags: android, dialog

I'm making a simple game, and when the game is over, it shows a custom Dialog with a play button(to restart the game),a TextView with the score obtained that time, another one with the best score, and finally 1 spinner that selects the game difficult for the next time. The Dialog should look like this:

[image]

But when i try the Dialog box it appears like this:

[image]

Any idea of what is happening?, i've been trying to put this in many different positions but still shows different...

The code of the Dialog is this:

```
public void pulsar(View v){
    final Dialog try_again = new Dialog(this);
    try_again.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    try_again.setCancelable(false);
    try_again.setContentView(R.layout.try_again);
    TextView SCORE = (TextView)try_again.findViewById(R.id.score);
    SCORE.setText(SCORE.getText().toString() + "80");//for example

    TextView BEST = (TextView)try_again.findViewById(R.id.best);
    BEST.setText(BEST.getText().toString() + "90");//for example

    Spinner sp = (Spinner)try_again.findViewById(R.id.sp);
    sp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,new String[]{"easy","normal","difficult"}));//for exmaple
    try_again.findViewById(R.id.play).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            recreate();
            try_again.dismiss();
        }
    });

    try_again.show();
}
```

and from the xml file of the dialog:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background">


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/play"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="SCORE : "
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:textColor="#ff989898"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/play"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/play"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="BEST : "
    android:id="@+id/best"
    android:textColor="#ff989898"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/score"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/play" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:popupBackground="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/play"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/best"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/best" />
```

Comment: set height and width of dialog to full screen.

Comment: @AhmadNawaz but it wouldn't be like i want, if it's possible, i'd like the dialog the be sized deppending of the layout file height and witdth, wrapping to the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/background">
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_map_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="SCORE : "
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:textColor="#ff989898"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/play"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="BEST : "
            android:id="@+id/best"
            android:textColor="#ff989898"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />


        </LinearLayout>



        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sp"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:popupBackground="@drawable/background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_map_header"/>
```